# Mouse-over text on link in comment not formatted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I noticed a bug. I was visiting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151638/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-false-in-python). I saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151638/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-false-in-python#comment93193717_53151638) containing a link to a Stack Overflow question. I hovered my mouse over the link in the comment, the mouse-over text appeared.

[image: why is python showing valueerror could not convert string to float?]

The text is not formatted **(no special characters included, title is lowercase)**.

I expected this:

[image: The same text with ValueError capitalized, quotation marks around the error message, and a question mark at the end.]

Comment: That title is generated from the link URL itself. Getting the true title would probably require at least one AJAX request.

Comment: @Xufox the title is not generated by your browser, it's put in the `title` attribute by Stack Overflow. They could easily put the formatted title in there too.

Comment: @Stijn I never said the `title` attribute was generated by the browser. The title attribute is generated (obviously by Stack Exchange) by replacing each `-` from `why-is-python-showing-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float` (as found in the URL) by a space. Getting the actual title likely would involve AJAX requests. Even if it wouldn’t, this change is probably not worth it. If this is going to be fixed, at least the actual link text should contain the question title as well.

Comment: Why would it involve AJAX requests at all? Their renderer backend now fills the title attribute with what you describe, it could instead pull the proper title from the database (or wherever it comes from).

Comment: Would certainly not require an AJAX request. It would require another DB hit per link per comment. Not saying that this is right or wrong, but the data has to come from somewhere.

Comment: I would retag this as a feature-request, since this is the expected behaviour and not a bug.

Comment: The beauty of how it currently works is that you can improve on the existing title. E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259728/stop-hovering-over-my-links

Answer (score 1):

Unlike posts, there's no pre-rendered version of comments stored in the database - they're converted into HTML every time the page is requested. This means that we can't retrieve the title of a linked question without parsing it out and issuing another query for every link (or, I suppose, one aggregate query for the entire set of comments if we're *very* careful) - no matter how you slice it, that's slower than *not* querying for titles.

So the title-tip is generated purely from the "slug" - that bit of text after the question ID in the URL itself. And the slug doesn't contain any information about which bits were capitalized, where there was punctuation, etc.

See also: [Tooltip for question links in comments showing sanitized title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182339/tooltip-for-question-links-in-comments-showing-sanitized-title)